# Datepicker not showing over a frame

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a `frameset` with 2 `frames` inside, the one on the top is opening a datepicker, but its not showing completely due to the lower frame...

I have tried increasing the `z-index` of the `ui-datepicker-div` but it's not working.

I'm posting an image so it can clarify any doubts about the question:

[image]

If this cannot be done, I'm open to new solutions (was thinking on opening a dialog, but I think it will be a mess).

Thanks in advance!

(I can't create a demo on jsFiddle cause apparently is not showing a frameset inside a frame)

Comment: are you being forced to use frames? using divs is way easier and is supported in html 4

Comment: Yes I'm force to use them, I can't change those frames...

Comment: I don't think you are able to show the datepicker outside the frame. Also, framesets are deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: @putvande It's something I can't change, it's an old software and new improvements are being made, removing `framesets` is making the software from the beginning. I need to solve this somehow...

Comment: just replace the location of the datepicker to go above the input field instead of below it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution (hack) would be that after the datepicker is shown, you could scroll to the bottom of the frame to display the whole datepicker.

Example:

```
$(".myDatepickers").datepicker({ 
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        // There's no On-/After Show event for datepicker (closest is beforeShow), 
        // so use a timeout-hack to wait until the datepicker has rendered
        // and then scroll.
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Get the document height, but you could also get the position + size 
            // of the datepicker to scroll just so that the datepicker will show.
            var scrollTo = $(document).height();

            // And scroll to the new position.
            $("html, body").scrollTop(scrollTo);
        }, 500); // Increase/decrease the timeout as needed.
    } 
});
```

If you have content after the datepicker, you can get the position of the datepicker and offset the size of the datepicker to get the scroll position.

Comment: Gonna try it, but do I have to catch the event when the datepicker is shown? I mean, where should I put this code?

Comment: thank you, lemme try it out. I think the size of the upper frame is dynamically set in the `<frameset rows="170,*">` but still, gonna try it, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @Luis Yeah, but that's the sizes for the frameset-container. The html-page in frame 1 has it's own size. So it will work anyway. And to be more clear, my example code should go into the html page in frame 1 (where the datepicker is).

Comment: It works! The problem is that this `.js` is called everywhere, I have to adjust it to work this way only when the datepicker is called from the top frame, also, when the datepicker is shown, I have to set the `height` of the `html` to `200px` which is the min size if the `datepicker`, when is set up to `170px` it is not shown completely. Thanks a lot, it was a great help!

Comment: @Luis No problems. You can also add your own data-attribute to the input that triggers the datepicker (i.e. `data-enableScroll="True"`)  and then add a check in the beforeShow method: `if ($(input).data("enableScroll")) { // do scrolling }` or `$(input).prop("data-enableScroll")` and then just add the attribute on the inputs you need. That way it get's a bit easier and cleaner.